# Email Macro - Different Subject Lines

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code I'm currently working with. I used this code over a few spreadsheets without issue; however, I was approached to modify it so the subject line can change based off of recipient.

In Column A I have the recipients and in Column G I have the unique subject lines. My expectation was an error on the Subject Line; but, instead the error is happening at the 'Next' line before .Display. Moreover, if I change the Subject line to Cells(i, "G").Value, then it errors out on the subject line as I expect.

Has anyone run into this scenario before? Google searches only bring up subject lines created from multiple cell references.

```
Sub EmailItems()

'Creates emails, attaches items, and choice to send automatically or have them pop up for your 
review. Delete the "'" in front of .Send in order to send automatically
    
Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim MailDest As String
Dim subj As String
Dim att As Variant
    
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Email").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'change 
worksheet as needed

For i = 2 To LastRow

    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set Attach = OutLookMailItem.Attachments

    With OutLookMailItem
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = [L6]
        .To = Cells(i, 1).Value
        .Cc = [L7]
        .Subject = Cells(i, 7).Value
        .Body = [L8] & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & [L10] & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & [L13] & 
         vbNewLine & [L14]
       On Error Resume Next
            For Each att In Split(Cells(i, 2).Value, ",")
            Attach.Add [L2] & att & [L3] 'change cell reference in brackets as needed
        Next
        .Display
        On Error GoTo 0
        '.Send
    End With

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You should really specify a worksheet for `[L6]`, `Cells(i, 7)` etc   Exactly what is the error you're getting?  Why do you expect an error with `Cells(i, "G").Value` ?

Comment: I'm getting Run-time '440' Object does not support this method. I expected the error to occur with Cells(i, "G").Value because it is the only line of code I changed. I ran it again, and the code occurred on the expected line rather than 'Next'.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me with all ranges fully-qualified: can't say what your exact issue is though.

```vb
Sub EmailItems()
    Dim OutLookApp As Object
    Dim att As Variant, ws As worksheet, atts, i As Long
        
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Email")
    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    
    For i = 2 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        With OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = ws.Range("L6").Value
            .To = Cells(i, 1).Value
            .Cc = ws.Range("L7").Value
            .Subject = ws.Cells(i, 7).Value
            .Body = ws.Range("L8").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    ws.Range("L10").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    ws.Range("L13").Value & vbNewLine & ws.Range("L14").Value
            
            atts = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
            If Len(atts) > 0 Then
                For Each att In Split(atts, ",")
                    On Error Resume Next
                    .Attachments.Add _
                        ws.Range("L2").Value & att & ws.Range("L3").Value
                    On Error GoTo 0
                Next
            End If 'any attachments
            .Display   'or .Send
            
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```